# Adding more than 1000 301 redirects in drupal site

Tags: redirect, drupal, drupal-6

I am using drupal 6.

I worked on the site revamp for one of our clients and we needed to redirect the old site urls to relevant new site urls so that we do not loose the traffic. I have used path redirect module for same and added some of the urls.

The issue is we have more than 1000 urls to be added and there is no specific pattern (as old site was in asp.) so it would be 1 to 1 mapping for redirect. Adding it in url alias table via path redirect module is something which is hitting the site performance and again it is a manual process.

Is there any other better and optimal solution for this scenerio?

Comment: What you meant by "hitting the site performance" ? Path Redirect module is working perfectly for me with several redirects and it's still better than adding tons of redirects to htaccess. Don't use the DB directly. There should be a php function to do that. Combining it with batch_api should do the trick perfectly i think

Comment: @AyeshK - I assume the OP means the database hits.  I believe path redirects are stored in the db by that module.  Would be interested in seeing a full answer from you with the PHP function solution you mentioned as well as its advantages over using .htaccess.

Answer (score 1):

http://drupal.org/project/path_redirect_import
This module has import feature out of the box.

Answer (score -1):

I'm interpreting this question as a question of performance (not a question of the ease of populating many redirects).  Please correct me if I've misunderstood your question.

**Put redirects in .htaccess**

If you're using Apache, then your alternative is to put the redirects directly into your [.htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) configurations.  There should be a similar configuration option for this for IIS as well.

This still means that you would have to create the 1 to 1 mapping for each redirect you want, but the redirects are not stored in your database so it saves hits to the db.

**Advantages to using Path Redirect module**

Note that the [Path Redirect module](http://drupal.org/project/path_redirect) can log when a redirect was last accessed.  This statistic/tracking can help you remove redirects that are no longer in use in the long run.

There are [posts on the Path Redirect issue queue](http://drupal.org/node/315926) that suggest that 1000 redirects should not be a problem but every setup is different.  You will need to perform your own benchmarking to check the performance of your particular site.

Comment: If you have thousands of redirects, do not add them to your .htaccess file (at least for Apache).  The .htaccess file is re-read and re-processed on every request (including for images, .js and .css files) and will slow your system significantly.  Add the redirects to your httpd.conf (or vhost.conf) file, which is read only once when the server starts or is reloaded, and will give you the functionality without the performance impact.